# Using a an imported module to refer to nested module

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but thought I understood how `import` statements work; the following example proves I do not.

```
# Works
from sklearn import tree
classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Doesn't work
import sklearn
classifier = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
# Error: AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'tree'
```

Since `tree` is itself another module I can't access it using dot syntax? Even if the "`from x import y`" is the canonical method, is it the *only* option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a module, Python looks for the module. It could be a "package", which is any directory with an `__init__.py` file. This file is imported as the name of the directory.

In your `__init__.py` file, you would usually have:

```
import name.sub_package.module_a
import name.sub_package.module_b
import name.module_c
```

to import the rest of the modules in the package, so they can be used directly. Sometimes, especially for bigger modules, the package author may decide not to, which shortens load times, as Python has to load less modules. This means that when you do:

```
from sklearn import tree
```

I am assuming the package looks a little like this:

```
sklearn/
    __init__.py
    tree/
        __init__.py
```

it imports `sklearn/__init__.py`, sees that there is no `tree`, then imports `sklearn/tree/__init__.py` as `tree`.

But, obviously `__init__.py` doesn't have `import sklearn.tree`, as it can't find it when you import it.

To fix this, import it manually:

```
import sklearn.tree
classifier = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```